# Diferencia entre distintos tipos de return

Tags: c++

¿Cual es la diferencia de añadirle un return -1 y un return 1 a una función cualquiera del tipo int? Leyendo el codigo de un programa que circulaba por un foro, en algunas funciones usaba return -1 y en otras usaba return 1.

Comment: return es el valor que va a regresar tras finalizar la operación, muchos usan 1 para marcar correcto, y -1 para un fallo

Comment: Pero no se supone que return 0 es que está correcto? @JorgeArturoJuarez

Comment: como te digo es preferencia de cada quien y su técnica de depuración, al final si no capturas ese dato no sirve de nada.

Comment: **Respuesta corta:** El valor numerico luego de la palabra `return` es algo dependiente de tu persona. **Informacion adicional:** por temas religiosos, cuando una funcion retorna `0`, es porque ha sido ejecutada con exito, de lo contrario, el valor retornado especifica el tipo de error si este tiene documentacion, lo que preguntas no es solo relacionado con [tag:c++], sino con otros _(Muchos)_ lenguajes que hacen uso de esta instruccion.

Comment: ¿No te estás referiendo al caso particular de la funcion `main()` no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respueta corta: Depende de ti.

## Respuesta Larga:

Depende de tí, puede ser de mucha diferencia. el return de una función es un mensaje que se manda desde la función llamada a la función que la invoco y no solo existen los valores -1 0 y 1 cuando hablas de una función int, ten en cuenta que los valores de de int van de -2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647. así que porque limitarse a -1 a 0  y a 1. Bueno en parte porque son numeros *sencillos* pero en la programación tu eres el programador y **tu tienes el poder**.

*Entonces por ejemplo puedes hacer una funcion suma;*

```
suma = funcion_suma(5, 2);
.
. 
.
int funcion_suma(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

y alli ves lo importante que es el return...

O puedes manejar tu propio *codigo secreto*

```
//si retorna 0 es porque el usuario quiere papas fritas 
//si retorna 1 quiere papas mas refresco
// si retorna 2 quiere helado de vainilla
// si retorna 52 quiere la cajita feliz
// si retorna -2 es porque no se decide
// si retorna -2000 se gano el premio
```

Sin embargo, si no te interesa para nada, si no capturas ese valor y empiezas a hacerte esa clase de preguntas, te recomiendo que hagas la funcion *void* y así no tendras esos dilemas existenciales